# Landscape Toggle Nav Can't Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

While in landscape view, I have a mobile nav that opens but wont scroll down to see more menu options. This is somewhat ok when nav is completely closed, however I have 2nd level toggle on an item that then prevents me from scrolling down. Is there a CSS fix for this I'm missing?

Nothing really special about how it's styled - jQuery does the open/close on the hamburger menu icon and the "Solar Service" link to open it up.

Note - viewing in responsive mode (Chrome) shows that the page is scrolling, but the nav isn't scrolling with the window. This header is also sticky / fixed to the top of the window.

Menu Closed
[image: Landscape view - menu closed]

Menu open
[image: Landscape view - menu open]

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but another SO post inpired the following work around

```css
/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */
  /* Landscape */
  @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 320px)
    and (max-device-width: 568px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; // mobile safari
  }

  /* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */
  /* Landscape */
  @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 375px)
    and (max-device-width: 667px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; // mobile safari
  }

  /* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */
  /* Landscape */
  @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 414px)
    and (max-device-width: 736px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
    and (orientation: landscape) {
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; // mobile safari
  }
```